# Castle Windsor and Session Per Web Request in MVC - How to deal with referential integrity issues when deleting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-windsor

I am using castle windsor and the session per web request pattern to manage NHibernate sessions.

As all commits are flushed at the end of the request, you lose ability to display an appropriate referential integrity error messages on the current page when doing deletes - if there is a ref integrity issue.

Not sure how others are managing this scenario, but I display all related issues to an action in the current view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally those sort of issues should be caught ahead of time by your validation and model layers. Do not rely on the database to tell you if something is wrong. DB is the last resort for that.

Comment: From the right guy ;-) So you reckon to do a query to determine if you are able to delete first?

Comment: Problem with this is no amount of validation will save you from concurrency issues.  Sometimes between the time you display a page and the time you get a request there will be changes that will invalidate the request. Most optimistic query techniques allow you to detect the concurrency issue in a single query, thus not requiring a transaction to lock rows with a select then delete. This requires you be able to execute the query and detect # rows effected.